# SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'payments' already exists (SQL: create table `payments`

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

When I migrate a table I see this error,

> SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table
>   'payments' already exists (SQL: create table `payments`

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreatePaymentsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('payments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->string('resnumber');
            $table->string('course_id')->default('vip');
            $table->string('price');
            $table->boolean('payment')->default(false);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('payments');
    }
}
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OrZvl.png)

Comment: do you have `payments` table already, share snapshot of all tables also ?

Comment: this may due to some table remain in the database so you may delete them and the problem will be solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to recreate the table, run [`php migrate:rollback`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations#rolling-back-migrations) first to delete the existing one. This command will run the `down()` method in the migration.

Then run `php migrate` to create the table again.

Answer (score 8):

If you are on Laravel 5.5 you can do `php artisan migrate:fresh`. This command will drop all tables und then create them again. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

If you have table in DB and dont want migrate create it, you can ignore it by check Schema::hasTable before create

```
    public function up()
{
    if(Schema::hasTable('products')) return;       //add this line to migration file
    Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->timestamps();

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case after `php migrate:rollback` resulted in `Nothing to rollback` and didn't solve. Because the `migrations` table in the database is empty.
So the solution is open up the tinker from the composer

```
$ php artisan tinker
>>> Schema::drop('users')
>>> Schema::drop('password_resets')
>>> Schema::drop('orders')
>>> exit
php artisan migrate
```

Here is the result of the above commands executed

```
nishanth@localhost:~/Desktop/html/hutch$ php artisan migrate
```

> In Connection.php line 647:
>                                                                                     SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users'
>   already exists (SQL: create table `users` (`id` int unsigned not
>   null auto_incr     ement primary key, `name` varchar(255) not null,
>   `email` varchar(255) not n     ull, `password` varchar(255) not null,
>   `remember_token` varchar(100) null,      `created_at` timestamp null,
>   `updated_at` timestamp null) default character      set utf8mb4
>   collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci)
>
> In Connection.php line 449:
>                                                                                     SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'users'
>   alre     ady exists

```
nishanth@localhost:~/Desktop/html/hutch$ php artisan migrate:rollback
Nothing to rollback.
nishanth@localhost:~/Desktop/html/hutch$ php artisan tinker
Psy Shell v0.8.17 (PHP 7.1.20-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 — cli) by Justin Hileman
>>> Schema::drop('users')
=> null
>>> Schema::drop('password_resets')
=> null
>>> Schema::drop('orders')
=> null
>>> exit
Exit:  Goodbye.
nishanth@localhost:~/Desktop/html/hutch$ php artisan migrate
Migrating: 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table
Migrated:  2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table
Migrating: 2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table
Migrated:  2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table
Migrating: 2018_08_18_071213_create_orders_table
Migrated:  2018_08_18_071213_create_orders_table
nishanth@localhost:~/Desktop/html/hutch$
```

Also define the method `down()`, if it doesn't exist. 
Otherwise, it'll show

> SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1051 Unknown table 'XYZ.ABC' (SQL: drop table `ABC`)

```
/**
  * Reverse the migrations.
  *
  * @return void
  */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('ABC');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first make php artisan migrate:rollback; then go to php my admin panel and drop the remaining table. then do php artisan migrate:fresh it will work :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is my scenario:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or
>   view already exists: 1050 Table 'migrations' already exists (SQL:
>   create table `migrations` (`id` bigint unsigned not null
>   auto_increment primary key, `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at`
>   timestamp null) default character set utf8mb4 collate
>   'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')

solution :

1. delete the file located in **YOUR-PROJECT/database/migrations/2020_02_04_031638_create_migrations_table.php**
2. run **php artisan migrate**, then your new table will create in your database

Answer (score 0):

Please use this command if you are using laravel 9 version

> php artisan migrate:fresh

This command will help to you. that's work for me.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error, the database table already exists. Below are possible solutions that can be helpful.

**Solution 1:**
Drop the entire database tables manually including the migrations table then re-run the `php artisan migrate` command.

**Solution 2:**
If you have some records in some of the existing tables and you don't want to drop/delete them. Then, click on the `migrations` table from your phpMyAdmin or related to see the list of the migrated tables. Delete/Edit the particular table that's causing the error and run the `php artisan migrate` command again.

**Solution 3:**
For some reason, you may want to run a particular migration file, the command below is what you need.

`php artisan migrate:refresh --path=/database/migrations/file-name.php`

Remember to replace the `file-name.php` with your actual file name.

I hope this will be helpful to someone.
:)